# What utility does rpm --import use to download keys?

Tags: fedora, rpm, dnf, http-proxy

I was trying to add [brave key](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux) to fedora repository. I am behind a http-proxy, so I am unable to connect.I wonder what utility (like wget or curl) does rpm use to download the keys? so that I can add proxy settings to that utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original document says

```
sudo rpm --import https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc
```

You can set the proxy on this line

eg

```
sudo env https_proxy=http://your.proxy.example.com:8080 rpm --import https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc
```

If you have a root shell (`su`) instead of using `sudo` then you can simply do

```
https_proxy=http://your.proxy.example.com:8080 rpm --import https://brave-browser-rpm-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc
```

Comment: That solved it. The Idea of custom variables, Super cool.